# how can i read the integer value from xml document in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this is my xml document, 
       i want to use the value of id and mlsid in in my
       viewcontroller.
       how can i read it.

```
       <Table>
        <ID>1</ID>
       <MLSID>70980420</MLSID>
       <STREET_NO>776</STREET_NO>
       <STREET_NAME>Boylston</STREET_NAME>
      <AreaName>Back Bay</AreaName
      <Table>
```

i have created one object file book which store the all value of xml data and then i put that objects in the array .
now i am able to retrive the string value but not getting the integer value.
this is my object class.

@interface Book : NSObject {

```
    NSInteger ID;
    NSInteger MLSID //Same name as the Entity Name.
}
```

how to trieve the value of MLSID in the viewcontroller.
or how to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an XML parser, of which there are [several options available](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+xml+parser).